# Wedge product of a one form and a two form

Tags: differential-geometry

How do we calculate $\omega \wedge \Omega$, if $\Omega$ is 2-form and $\omega = dv$? The ambient manifold is $R^{4}$ with coordinates $x$, $y$, $v$ and $w$.
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you consult R.M. Wald's textbook on General Relativity, and in particular Appendix B on Differential Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question right then $\Omega=A dx\wedge dy + B dx\wedge dv + C dx\wedge dw + D dy\wedge dv + E dy\wedge dw + F dv\wedge dw$ for some choice of functions $A,B,C,D,E,F$. Then using the alternating property of the wedge product you will loose the terms $B dx\wedge dv, D dy\wedge dv, Fdv\wedge dw$ due to $dv\wedge dv\wedge dx = -dv\wedge dv \wedge dx$ and will in the end obtain a 3-Form.